# al enviar el link para restablecer la contraseña me dice problema con "Lang"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

aqui anexo una foto del problema, no se bien que deberia hacer, asumo que se refiere al lenguaje?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes importar el facade para poderlo utilizar:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
// ...
```